# descriptive stats for two categorical variables (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to get the mean and median for frequencies between two categorical variables. E.g.:

**Label Letter Num**

Foo | A | 1

Foo | B | 2

Foo | C | 4

Bar | A | 2

Bar | G | 3

Bar | N | 1

Bar | P | 2

Cee | B | 1

Cee | B | 2

Cee | C | 4

Cee | D | 5

For instance, what's the mean and median number of letters per label. Here there are 11 cases out of three possible labels (M=3.667) and the median is 4 (3 foo, 4 bar, 4 cee). How can I calculate this in pandas. Is it possible to do this with a groupby statement?  My data set is much larger than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for one column or [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) (or [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) if need omit `NaN`s):

```
a = df['Label'].value_counts()
print (a)
Cee    4
Bar    4
Foo    3
Name: Label, dtype: int64

#alternative
#a = df.groupby('Label').size()
print (a.mean())
3.6666666666666665

print (a.median())
4.0
```

---

```
a = df.groupby(['Label','Letter']).size()
print (a)
Label  Letter
Bar    A         1
       G         1
       N         1
       P         1
Cee    B         2
       C         1
       D         1
Foo    A         1
       B         1
       C         1
dtype: int64

print (a.mean())
1.1

print (a.median())
1.0
```

Comment: I have an off topic question. How do you import the OP's data in your dataframe?

Comment: Or better is `sep="\s+\|\s+|\s+"` - not necessary add `|` to headers

Comment: @jezrael, could you please advise on this related question. Thanks!